# Algorithm for n-tuple Summation

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, sum, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to write computer programm for some mathematical formula, in which I came across with n-tuple Summation, by which I mean $ \sum \sum \sum \dddot $. I am searching for efficient algorythm to write code in python. For exapmle: $$ \sum_{j_1}^{a_1} \sum_{j_2}^{a_2}   \dddot  , \sum_{j_i}^{a_i} f(j_1,j_2, \dddot , , j_i) $$  One method that I can see, is to generate one big list with size probably $ a_1 \dot a_2 \dot \dddot , a_i $ and iterate over it. But i think it is not perfect way and there exist better solution. Number of sums aren't fixed, in other words, numbers of sigma notations in expresion can be any number.

Answer (score 2):

Without some insight into what `f()` does, there isn't much you can do in the way of optimization. You might as well keep your code simple-

```py
from itertools import starmap, product

def calcsum(func, intervals):
    ranges = starmap(range, intervals)
    args = product(*ranges)
    return sum(starmap(func, args))
```